# Microsoft JScript Error : Syntax Error 800A03EA in node js

Tags: node.js, npm

There is a function where milliseconds is passed and there is a constant which i have to declare in that function as shown below,

```
function run(context, callback, milliseconds) {
    // time to wait for a service to stop in milliseconds
    const waitMilliseconds = milliseconds || 180000;
    const interval = 15000;
   // other stuff

}
```

When I run npm install in the command line I get a Microsoft JScript error and it shows syntax error at this line :

```
const waitMilliseconds = milliseconds || 180000;
```

When I change 'const' to 'var' there is no error.

I am using the latest node version Node 10.11.0
npm 6.4.1

Comment: const only one time initialization . you can't manipulation the const.

Answer (score 4):

Faced the same issue. But after changing the file name it is working fine.

**Before change:**

node "node.js"

**After Change:**

node "nodesample.js"

Comment: this worked for me, can someone explain why this would be the case in windows?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing... I found out I wasn't writing "node" on the console... Mistakes were made.

Instead of writing `node .\myFile argument1 argument2` I was writing `.\myFile argument1 argument2`

I felt very stupid after that but mistakes are there so you can learn...